# fetch appinsight traces from java application

Tags: spring-boot, appinsights

How can i fetch logs from appinsight from Spring application? I don't want the metrics as official documents suggest. Is there a way to execute custom queries on trace, exception tables and extract the results for a Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the [REST API - Query](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference/get-query)

**GET /v1/apps/{appId}/query**

Example from the documentation:

```
{
 "appId": "34adfa4f-cedf-4dc0-ba29-b6d1a69ab345",
 "query": "requests | take 10",
 "timespan": "PT12H"
}
```

This works also for traces, etc.:

```
{
 "appId": "34adfa4f-cedf-4dc0-ba29-b6d1a69ab345",
 "query": "traces | order by timestamp",
 "timespan": "PT12H"
}
```